# Why can wine run 64bit programs on Linux but not on Mac?

Tags: linux, osx, wine, 64bit

I read about a developer saying it doesn't work, "and probably never will". Why is this? The two OSes aren't that radically different, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine on macOS can run 64-bit applications since version 2.0. [Here are the release notes for 2.0](https://www.winehq.org/announce/2.0)

> The main highlights are the support for
>   Microsoft Office 2013, **and the 64-bit support on macOS**.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Also how the heck did they manage to do that given the previous explanation of why it is not possible?

Comment: @psusi I guess Apple must have made a change to their operating system making it possible

Answer (score 8):

The answer is given in a mailing list comment by Stefan Dösinger entitled *[Wine 64 bit](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2014-February/103074.html)*

> OSX has a ABI incompatibility with Win64 - OSX overwrites a CPU register that Win64 applications expect to remain untouched. Apple can’t change the ABI because there are already 64 bit OSX apps that expect things to work that way. A potential workaround may be to run Wine inside a CPU emulator like qemu, but that is anything but easy.